# Set theoretic proof involving union and intersection identity

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to prove that $$A\cap(B\cup C)=(A\cap B)\cup C  \implies C\subset A$$
without returning back to symbolic logic. I've tried expanding with the distributive identities but it's not very clear to me of how to proceed from that...

Comment: Try the contrapositive! Assume there is some element $x \in C$ that is *not* in $A$, then show that it contradicts the equation on the LHS.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Thank you! That's a good point. I'll have to try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume x in C.  Then x in $(A\cap B)\cup C.$
Thus x in $A\cap(B\cup C)$, x in A.